# How to run neural network in gpu instead of cpu?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I installed **cuDNN** and **cuda toolkit 11** in my machine. Now I installed **tensorflow-gpu** in pip3 of version 2.2.0. But while running neural network, cpu is being used **90%** with four cores and gpu is being used just **7%-15%**. But I want my cpu will not be used.

Comment: What version of TensorFlow are you using?

Comment: tensorflow-2.2.0

Comment: Since tf 2.1 on, you don't need anymore to install `tensorflow-gpu`. Just simply `pip install tensorflow` and it will take care of GPUs